# Export certificate as pfx

Tags: certificate, private-key, pfx, p12

I'm trying to export my certifcate as pfx. I'm doing that my certmgr.msc but some of the options are gray.
[certmgr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCrrp.png)
So I wanted to use `Powershell` for this.
I'm going to the catalogue where the certificate is located (cert:\CurrentUser\My) and I'm inducing a syntax:

```
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert .\4BBB***************************** -FilePath 'C:\Users\jwozniak\Documents\outfile.pfx' -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'password63' -AsPlainText -Force)
```

(without * of course)

And I get an below error:
[image]

I'd appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Better to add error in question directly, rather than adding Image.

Comment: Edit: now i've got an error "cannot expoer non-exportable private key"
Question is: how to import certificate with option exportable private key?

Comment: A certificate (on windows) has export policies. You cannot get around that except using for instance https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz

Answer (score 1):

When a certificate is created, You need to make private key has "Exportable".
Then only  `Export-PfxCertificate` command works fine without errors.

Some of examples which may help you :

1)For creating self signed certificate by marking private key has Exportable

`$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName $certname -certStorelocation cert:\localmachine\my -KeyLength 2048  -KeyFriendlyName $certname -FriendlyName $friendlyName -HashAlgorithm sha256 -Keyexportpolicy Exportable`

Here parameter -Keyexportpolicy plays an important role for serving the purpose.

2)For Your question *how to import certificate with option exportable private key ?*
Follow the below command

```
 Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath C:\Temp\$certname.pfx -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root -Password $certpwd1 -Exportable
```

Here parameter -Exportable plays an important role for serving the purpose

Answer (score 0):

A certificate (on windows) has export policies. You cannot get around that except using for instance https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz